# Visual Studio npm install on TFS get-latest

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, npm-install

When TFS "get latest" pulls in a package.json change that adds a dev dependency, Visual Studio 2017 doesn't automatically run "npm install". This breaks any gulp tasks in "watch" mode that depend on the new package.

The only way I can see to cause an npm install is to manually touch package.json or restart VS.

Is there a way to trigger "npm install" on "get latest"?

Comment: maybe jerry-rig a watcher/service that triggers the install in powershell or something? good question though, I'm not aware of conditions or parameters for get-latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a wireframe of the solution I settled on. tl;dr - implement my own package.json watcher in Gulp to stop Webpack, run `npm install`, and restart Webpack.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const install = require('gulp-install');
const watch = require('glob-watcher');
const webpack = require('webpack');

gulp.task('default', ['webpack']);

gulp.task('webpack', function () {
    // Start the initial Webpack build.
    let webpackCompiler = webpack({
        // ...
        watch: true
        // ...
    });

    // Set up a watcher to kill Webpack, run 'npm install', and restart Webpack when package.json changes.
    let packageWatcher = watch('./package.json', { events: ['change'] }, () => {
        packageWatcher.close();
        console.log('Stopped package.json watcher.');

        webpackWatcher.close(() => {
            console.log('Stopped Webpack watcher.');

            gulp.start('npm-install-then-webpack');
        });
    });
    console.log('Started package.json watcher.');
});

gulp.task('npm-install', function (callback) {
    gulp.src('./package.json')
        .pipe(install(callback));
});

gulp.task('npm-install-then-webpack', ['npm-install'], function () {
    gulp.start('webpack');
});
```

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT thanks. Marking as correct, even though I wish there were a native solution. Anyone curious can follow [my question](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/296850/tfs-get-latest-w-packagejson-change-doesnt-trigger.html) on Visual Studio Development Community to see if Microsoft moves to implement this natively.